# Иконка из DirectoryEntry по типу объекта

Tags: c#, active-directory

Реально ли получить иконку из ресурсов `Windows` по типу объекта из `DirectoryEntry`?

Comment: Не знаете, в каком именно файле расположена? Google подсказывает, что здесь: `C:\WINNT\system32\dsuiext.dll`.

Comment: Спасибо, а теперь как мне можно узнать какая из иконок к какому типу из DirectoryEntry относиться?

Comment: Подозреваю, что методом сличения. Взять любой resource icon viewer, коих Google предоставляет десятки, и посмотреть глазами. Номер иконки, необходимый для её загрузки, программа для просмотра должна показывать.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не в курсе сколько существует типов объекта в AD и какие они должны иметь иконки из dsuiext.dll... Хотя, можно перебрать все объекты предприятия и глянуть уникальные типы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `dsuiext.dll` есть функция [`DsGetIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675990(v=vs.85).aspx), которая по имени класса объекта LDAP вернет иконку для него. Для `DirectoryEntry` класс объекта находится в свойстве `objectclass`:

```
[Flags]
enum IconType : uint
{
    DSGIF_ISNORMAL = 0x0000000,
    DSGIF_ISOPEN = 0x0000001,
    DSGIF_ISDISABLED = 0x0000002,
    DSGIF_ISMASK = 0x000000f,
    DSGIF_GETDEFAULTICON = 0x0000010,
    DSGIF_DEFAULTISCONTAINER = 0x0000020 
}

[DllImport("dsuiext.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern IntPtr DsGetIcon(IconType dwFlags, string pszObjectClass, int cxImage, int cyImage);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=mydomain,DC=local");
    var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
    {
        PageSize = int.MaxValue,
        Filter = "<какой-то фильтр>"
    };

    var result = searcher.FindOne();
    var objectClass = result.Properties["objectclass"][0].ToString();

    var icon = DsGetIcon(IconType.DSGIF_ISNORMAL, objectClass, 32, 32);
    if (icon != IntPtr.Zero) {
        using (var img = Icon.FromHandle(icon)) {
            pictureBox1.Image = img.ToBitmap();
        }
        DestroyIcon(icon);
    }
}
```

Не для всех значений свойства `objectclass` функция что-то возвращает. Однако, в dsuiext.dll можно найти строки, которые работают (без учета регистра):

```
builtInDomain
computer
configuration
rpcContainer
contact
container
domainDNS
domainPolicy
group
localGroup
localPolicy
nTDSConnection
nTDSDSA
nTDSSettings
organizationalPerson
organizationalUnit
person
printQueue
remoteMailRecipient
server
serverConnection
site
sitesContainer
storage
subnet
subnetContainer
user
volume
workStationAccount
licensingSiteSettings
nTDSSiteSettings
siteLink
siteLinkBridge
nTFRSSettings
nTFRSReplicaSet
nTFRSSubscriptions
nTFRSSubscriber
nTFRSMember
foreignSecurityPrincipal
interSiteTransport
interSiteTransportContainer
serversContainer
inetOrgPerson
msDS-ManagedServiceAccount
msDS-GroupManagedServiceAccount
```

Comment: Ой спасиб добрый человек. Попробую в пн. Поверю что это решение на слово.